# ASP.NET multiple Eval fields

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

I need to include multiple Eval fields in the Navigate URL field of a hyperlink control, however, the code I have tried does not work.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlkImageLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("getProductIDGV","getProductCategoryNameGV","getProductCategoryIDGV", "~/PT_productdetails.aspx?ProductID={0}&amp;CategoryName={1}&amp;CategoryID={2}") %>'>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
NavigateUrl= '<%# String.Format("~/PT_productdetails.aspx?ProductID={0}&CategoryName={1}&CategoryID={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("getProductIDGV")), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("getProductCategoryNameGV")), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("getProductCategoryIDGV"))) %>'
```

Comment: Thanks but getting the error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: @burntsugar - Sorry. I changed the UrlEncode to be called from HttpUtility - it was not a static (shared) method of HttpServerUtility.